# Marking the wrong row using an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i need advice with one SQL query. I have table:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[MATNR] as type
      ,[VLPLA] as whence
      ,[NLPLA] as whither
      ,[TIMESTAMP]
  FROM [DNMST].[dbo].[Visualization]


 ID        type      whence  whither    TIMESTAMP
9430945  1465C04080  TRANSFER  GH-001    2020-10-02 12:35:48.000
9479333  1465C04073  GH-001    GH-004    2020-10-02 14:05:51.000
9705379  1465C04080  TRANSFER  GH-001    2020-10-02 20:59:12.000
9705380  1465C04080  TRANSFER  GH-001    2020-10-02 20:59:22.000
9705658  1465C04080  TRANSFER  GH-002    2020-10-02 20:59:52.000
12411110 1465C04073  GH-004    GH-001    2020-10-06 07:35:51.000
```

And I need to mark the wrong line. The "whither" column indicates where only one type can be located (the "type" column). In place of GH-001 was the first type '4080' (according to the "timestamp") but then the same place was added type '4073'. I need to mark this line as bad. I tried it before DENSE_RANK and then created the conditions, but I couldn't.
When i used:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,RIGHT(MATNR,24) as type
      ,[VLPLA] as whence
      ,[NLPLA] as whither
      ,[TIMESTAMP]
      ,DENSE_RANK() over (partition by MATNR,NLPLA order by timestamp desc) as status
  FROM [DNMST].[dbo].[Visualization]
```

I get status 1 twice for GH-001 (column "whither") And just one of these two is wrong (the one that is newer)

I tried this for example, but it's also wrong.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,RIGHT(MATNR,24) as type
      ,[VLPLA] as whence
      ,[NLPLA] as whither
      ,[TIMESTAMP]
      ,DENSE_RANK() over (partition by MATNR,NLPLA order by timestamp desc) as status,
      CASE WHEN  (DENSE_RANK() over (partition by MATNR,NLPLA order by timestamp desc) = 1  AND NLPLA=NLPLA THEN 'WRONG'
      ELSE 'Right'
      End AS status_text

  FROM [DNMST].[dbo].[Visualization]
```

How is the correct sql query?
Thx

Comment: Do you actually want `partition by RIGHT(MATNR,4)`? if not, the I would suggest that the values of `MATNR` are different, and hence why they both got a "rank" of `1`.

Comment: Also, you have a `TOP` but forgot to put an `ORDER BY` in your query. If you are using `TOP` you **need** to put an `ORDER BY` in there or your results will not be consistent (if they are, then it is pure chance, and you should not expect them to stay that way).

Comment: @Larnu Even though I adjust these things, it still doesn't work for me. I use RIGHT only for better illustration.

Comment: Take the time, then, to post your sample data in a **consumable** format. Images of data don't help us help you. Then we can run your code, and replicate the problem.

Comment: @Larnu ok, i updated. This is my whole table (it's small). But even so, I can't compile the required query, which would mark the wrong line for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `FIRST_VALUE()` analytic function

```
CASE WHEN [TYPE] <> FIRST_VALUE([TYPE]) OVER (PARTITION BY whither ORDER BY timestamp)
     THEN 'WRONG' ELSE 'RIGHT' END
```

[FIRST_VALUE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/hh213018(v=sql.110))

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this query identifies the rows where the 'type' for a 'whither' is different than the earliest 'type' assigned.

```
with whither_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by whither order by [timestamp] rn
    from [DNMST].[dbo].[Visualization])
select * 
from [DNMST].[dbo].[Visualization] v
     join whither_cte wc on v.whither=wc.whither
                            and v.ID<>wc.ID
                            and v.[type]<>wc.[type]
                            and wc.rn=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (
                FIRST_VALUE([type]) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY [whither] ORDER BY [TIMESTAMP]
                    )
                ) <> [type]
            THEN 'Bad'
        ELSE 'Good'
        END AS [Status]
FROM  [DNMST].[dbo].[Visualization]
```